# foreach to an object list

Tags: c#, foreach

given a list of objects, i save them to a text file like this:

```
public void Save(PhoneBook pb)
{
   foreach (PhoneBookGroup item in pb.Items)
   {
        File.WriteAllText(path, item.GroupName + "@");
        foreach (Contect contect in item.Items)
       {
           File.WriteAllText(path, "Group :" + item.GroupName + "#"+
                                   "Name : " + contect.Name + "$" +
                                   "Number : " + contect.Number + "$" +
                                   "Addres : " + contect.Addres + "$");
       }
   }
}
```

the result is : Group :group Aaa#Name : Ziv$Number : 1$Addres : Sokolov$

now i want to load from that file while keeping the logic and add each group to a list. using a char finder that look for the (# for the object name and $ for the attributes name) example:

```
Aaa(object)  
ziv(attributes)  
1(attributes)  
sokolov(attributes)
```

and so on

```
bbb(object)  
jon(attributes)  
2(attributes)  
somewhere(attributes)
```

.

```
public void Load()
{
   List<PhoneBook> phoneBookList = new List<PhoneBook>();

   string line = File.ReadAllText(path);
   foreach (var item in line)
   {

   }
   return phoneBookList;
```

}

Comment: You should use a standard structured file specification (e.g. XML or JSON) rather than roll your own.

Comment: How about serializing instead of using your own method?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use `WriteAllText` here. [Please, *read the docs!*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) They state: "**Creates a new file**, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is **overwritten**." IOW, every iteration in your writing loop replaces what you had written before.

Comment: the point is not to use serializing  methods... i allready did it in json. :)

Comment: @darko: If you really need your own data format, you will have to find a way to separate your `line` between the different records.

Comment: As pointed out it's much better to use a standarized file format. Otherwise you can add a \n (linebreak) after each record and then use regular expressions to extract the data from between your #, : and $'s.